# Is there any way to make labels selectable in SWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

Is there any way to make labels selectable in SWT? or are there any other widgets in SWT that are selectable and can be used as labels? I am building a calendar.

Comment: What do you mean by "selectable"? You can add a `Listener` for `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` to the `Label`.

Comment: Yes exactly I want to add listener to label. How can I do that?

Comment: So do you want to actually select the text (to copy it somewhere) or do you want to check for click events?

Comment: I want to check for click events.

Comment: If you want to check for click events, then why did you accept an answer suggesting to use a `StyledText`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to select the `Label` text to clipboard.

You can use `Text` Widget as Label but caret will appear when user clicks on it.
If you don't want caret then use `StyledText` and set caret to null.

Example:

```
package testplugin;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class SWTHelloWorld {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Label labelWidget = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    labelWidget.setText("Hello");

    Text textWidget = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
    textWidget.setText("Hello");

    //Set background color same as its container
    textWidget.setBackground(shell.getBackground());
    //Make editable false
    textWidget.setEditable(false);

    StyledText styledTextWidget = new StyledText(shell, SWT.NONE);
    styledTextWidget.setText("Hello");  
    styledTextWidget.setBackground(shell.getBackground());
    styledTextWidget.setEditable(false);
    //Set caret null this will hide caret
    styledTextWidget.setCaret(null);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open ();
    shell.setSize(200, 300);
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

---

You can refer these links to listen mouse,keyboard,focus etc etc listeners on various widgets.

- [Typed listeners](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/TypedListeners.htm)
- [Un typed listeners](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/IntroducingUntypedListeners.htm)
- [Introduction to SWT Widget](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=354574&seqNum=3)

Comment: I think even a simple `Text` would be sufficient here.

Comment: How we can hide caret on Text widget?

Comment: You can't. But that wasn't a requirement.

Comment: I had to use StyledText, I tried using simple Text but couldn't get rid of the border which made it look more like a button than a label. And the caret was an eye-sore too. But StyledText works nicely.